# Why are custom tabs not displayed correctly in contact summary?

Tags: 4.7, display

My users have reported seeing custom tabs not displaying correctly in the contact summary screen. Instead of wrapping, the tabs display as below. I can't reproduce the problem, although I have seen it in the past.  This is Civi 4.7.19  running with Drupal. Theme is 'Seven'
[image]

Comment: Andy - for interface type issues, usually worth mentioning your CMS and theme, and also confirming if the issue is evident on a demo site. That helps rule in/out whether it is unique to your configuration/set up

Comment: ok but you didn't mention theme. garland?

Comment: Oops, the theme is 'Seven'

Comment: i tried setting one of my sites to use Seven for civicrm and had no issue with the display of the Tabs. Do you know how to use your browser inspector to check for console errors?

Answer (score 1):

Tried replicating the issue, but couldn't. Its working fine with Civi 4.7.19 on drupal 7.56 and theme 'Seven'. It maybe because of some conflicting css class.